# error Cannot find module 'semver' in (npm run dev) command

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

im using laravel 8 and vuejs to create my website

i have this error after run `npm run dev` command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
...
```

[image]

id tried this solutions:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs --auto-remove
sudo apt-get purge npm --auto-remove

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
npm i -g semver
```

and then installed again the `nodejs` and `npm` (latest version)

but the error still exist
what should i do

Comment: have you tried `npm i -g semver`

Comment: i tried. but still error

Comment: You did it globally right?

Comment: You can also try `cd /usr/share/npm; npm i semver`

Comment: @Shubham Kumar. well i have this error now: Cannot find module 'npmlog'

Comment: Great thats a progress. I have posted a answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some modules missing in your `/usr/share/npm`.
So this will I guess solve the problem

```sh
cd /usr/share/npm; npm i
```

If this doesn't work then you can also just go on installing each missing module in `/usr/share/npm`.

Comment: Followed your idea.
I ended up forcing a global install of npm:
`sudo npm install -g npm`
which fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: same error with your line

Answer (score 3):

just try to install npm globally , it will install latest version of npm

```
 sudo npm install -g npm
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

The error is basically saying you are missing the module, so you need to install it this way :

```
npm install semver
```

Comment: @K1-Aria have you tried to do `npm init` inside the folder ? And have you run that command inside your project where you run the command npm run dev ?

Comment: yes, now. when i try (npm init) it will give me same error (Cannot find module 'semver'
)

Comment: Is there any directory named node_modules in your project ? @K1-Aria